# Manipulation with integer int to hex conversions

Tags: java, hex, int

I know is simple and I know that is asked many times but still I couldn't find the thing I am looking for.

I have a value from 0 to 500 it is a int.
I want to have an output from 0x00 to 0xFF.

```
public void method(int i)// 0-500
{
return the_proportional_value_in_hex_in_range_0_to_ff;
}
```

can someone writhe me a converter from this kind. Thanks

EDIT

I DO **NOT** wanted a exact conversion, I just wanted a SCALED conversion, and @Mac answered exactly what I needed.

Comment: First you cannot return in a void method, then values are not stored in hex or numbers, they are all stored as binary numbers so maybe what you need is to convert it to a string. Please update your question

Comment: I do not want exact conversion, I want scaled

Comment: you do know that 0xFF is only 256, you'll need another bit to get to 500 (or lose accuracy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int scaled = (i * 255) / 500;`

`i / 500` scales `i` to the range `0 ... 1`, then multiply by 255 (i.e. `0xFF`) scales that to `0 ... 255`. Doing it the other way around (multiply then divide) is just to prevent numeric underflow on the divide.

To print as hex, you could use `System.out.printf("%x", scaled);`. I say print, because talking about a "hex value" isn't terribly useful.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a value from 0 to 500 it is a int. I want to have an output
>   from 0x00 to 0xFF

Bad luck, it is impossible. You need 9 bits for that. 500 = 0x1F4.